# Database (Access) update not possible

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am getting weird output while updating database Access (2007). I am using VB.net as front-end and back-end Access system database. Now, I run the query of Insert with property parameters. I am updating two texts boxes inputs into the database.

My query runs fine sometimes but sometimes acts weird. For e.g.: 
I have database:

```
Field 1    Field 2
A           ABC
B           XYZ (last updated entry)
```

Now, if i enter C LMN as new entry then it takes my previous entry of B XYZ and auto number field increase the value and database become like,

```
Field 1    Field 2
A           ABC
B           XYZ  
B           XYZ (last updated entry which was suppose to be C LMN)
```

I tried to clear text boxes, command variable etc. but when i close my program and re-execute the same then it works fine.

If we guess of closing the database connection and re-opening it then in that case other queries are working fine.

Can anybody suggests solution or Any Access related setting which i am missing.

EDIT: It is observed that, it is updating database only one time. Next time it is considering previously updated last data and inserting same into database.

-abhimoh

Comment: Can you post the code that performs the update?

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO groups " +
                "([group_name], [group_desc])" +
                "VALUES(@p1, @p2)"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtgrp.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtgrpdesc.Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Try to debug your code putting breakpoints on the instructions that assign values to the parameters: probably your application is passing the old values instead of the new ones

Comment: Yes i performed debug already. It is fetching new values only. But while updating (executenonquery) statement it is updating old values. Very strange!

Comment: Found the solution. I am disposing cmd (command) and reassigning connection to it before executing query (closing the thread)